# Ember CLI (4.1.0) github output

Tags: git, github, ember.js, atom-editor

I am new emberjs and trying to track my project via github. I currently have a directory tracking my changes `/workspace`, which should contain a subdirectory `/workspace/currentproj`. The top level directory is being tracked by my github however the lower level changes are not. When I check the status on `currentproj` the files are being track but not by my remote repo. In the `ember-cli-update.json` file I see a reference to a `"outputRepo": "https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output"`. I am wondering if that is where I need to add my repo information. If so its not working. How do track changes using my current repo?

I am using a mac air m1 with atom editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tricky to help you here, because you mix `ember` and `git` things, while they are actually unrelated.

About the `ember-cli-update.json`: you should *not* edit this, the `outputRepo` is about where `ember-cli-upgrade` will take the output of a new ember app to upgrade your app.

Now, also try to avoid mixing `git` and `github`. Github is an online platform for git, but the tool you locally use it `git`, and unrelated to `github`. Its the other way around: Github is a platform for `git`, not `git` is a tool from Github.

I'm not sure how you created the `git` repos, but one importing thing here: `ember new` by default *generates a `git` repo*! Now I assume your issue may be the following:

- you created a new ember project within `/workspace` named `currentproject`, *before* there was a `git` repository for `/workspace`.
- this created the new folder `/workspace/currentproj`, which is a `git` repository.
- you then created a git reposity for `/workspace`, now you have 2 nested git repositories.

To investigate this its important to understand one thing: A git repository is a folder with a `.git` folder in it. Nothing else, there is no magic to it. This is how you can move a folder containing a repo around.

I would suggest to check if there is a `/workspace/currentproj/.git` folder. If there is, you probably can safely *delete it*, since you want git to use the `/workspace/.git` repo for this subfolder.

---

If this was *not* your issue another thing could be, that `git status` does not list files folders without tracked files. You will only see the folder. However a `git add --all` should add these files, so this could also be a possible issue.

---

Generally when troubleshooting `git` its good to look for `.git` folders and investigate the output of `git status` and `git log`. In your case you could run these commands from within `/workspace` and `/workspace/currentproj` and compare to investigate.

Comment: Right removing the submodule and running the command git rm --cached project allowed me to get my project to my github repo.